# comparing 2 arrays of characters in java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to simply compare 2 arrays of Strings. The overall purpose of the code is to go through each index of the arrays and  compare the two at each index(a[1] == b[1]) and add to a 3 array the number a 1 when the two arrays are the same. When finished it will print out the size of the array as the total number of times the two are the same. When i try to compare the code i get an error. I have tried commenting out and testing and it seems to have a problem with my comparison statement on line 23.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Slop 
{  

public static void main(String [] args)  
{  
     // Compare the 2 Signatures
     String control = " 0x302E0215032648D0ABE03F7226239932B9293B157F3EECF863021503635EB910778742D88A880B867C45CFFDEC9970BC";
     char[] controlArray = control.toCharArray();
    //System.out.println(controlArray);
     String test = "0x302E021501452CB212DBE4C8B541D02D79EF140BE617875EC7021503951DB8026549B0F9AB8FDB69F355F37A5A967424";
     char[] testArray = test.toCharArray();
     List<Integer> countArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    // try{
     for(int i =0; i < 99; i++)
     {
         //System.out.println(controlArray[i]);
         for(int j =0; j < 99; j++)
         {
            //System.out.println(controlArray);
             //System.out.println(testArray[j]);
             if (controlArray[i] == testArray[j])
             {
                countArray.add(1);

             }


         }

     }
     System.out.println(countArray.size());
}}}
```

I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 98
at Slop.main(Slop.java:23)
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why 2 loops if you want to compare each element at the same index?

Comment: <array>.length is your friend. Also, why are you comparing each character in one array to each in the other?

Comment: 1. Is that space at the start of `control` supposed to be there? 2. I can't be bothered to *count* the number of characters. Are you sure there are 100 in each string? Your error suggests it's not.

Comment: Why are you using 99, use controlArray.length or testArray.length instead. Your controlArray has one more character, since there is a space at the beginning of control variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the command: `controlArray.length` instead of guessing the length of the array.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Slop 
{  
   public static void main(String [] args)   
   {  
     // Compare the 2 Signatures
     String control = "0x302E0215032648D0ABE03F7226239932B9293B157F3EECF863021503635EB910778742D88A880B867C45CFFDEC9970BC";
     char[] controlArray = control.toCharArray();
     String test    = "0x302E021501452CB212DBE4C8B541D02D79EF140BE617875EC7021503951DB8026549B0F9AB8FDB69F355F37A5A967424";
     char[] testArray = test.toCharArray();
     List<Integer> countArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

     for(int j =0; j < controlArray.length; j++)
     {
         if (controlArray[j] == testArray[j])
         {
            countArray.add(1);
         }
     }
     System.out.println(countArray.size());
   }
}
```

Comment: this still explodes if controlArray is longer than testArray.

Comment: I assumed the array would be same length because it uses hard coded values which were the same length.

Answer (score 0):

It says your index is out of bounds.
When I check our arrays it looks like, you have 99 elements in controlArray and 98 elements testArray.
Please check that and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: I made them both 0x302 and i still have the same error              `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Slop.main(Slop.java:23)`

Answer (score 0):

Introductory Comments (true, but not nice):

- Stop using stupid variable names.  Single character variable names provide exactly one piece of information "the author of this code is careless" (edited for less opinionated).
- Just keep a count of how many characters are the same in an int variable.  Using a dynamic array is seriously overkill.

The Answer:
Note: This answer matches the description of the problem, but not your implementation of the problem.
Try the following:

```
int countOfSameChars = 0;
int shortestLength;

// First, figure out the length of the shortest string.
if (controlArray.length <= testArray.length)
{
    shortestLength = controlArray.length;
}
else
{
    shortestLength = testArray.length;
}

// Avoid array out of bounds errors by iterating only to the shortest length.
for (int index = 0; index < shortestLength; ++index)
{
    if (controlArray[index] == testArray[index])
    {
        ++countOfSameChars;
    }
}

System.out.println("Blam: " + countOfSameChars);
```

Your description of the problem implies the following:
If controlArray = "11" and testArray = "01", the desired count is 1 because controlArray[0] != testArray[0] and controlArray[1] == testArray[1].

Comment: i have tried making the 2 the same size and i still get the error would this solution help that?

Comment: The solution is delete your code and replace it with my code.

Comment: Also thank you for the tips im still a fairly poor coder and tips like this while blunt are always nice to hear.

Comment: My solution is only correct if the problem matches the problem I describe in the last part (following the code) of my post.  If you want the count to be 2 in that situation (because there are zero '0' characters and two '1' characters in controlArray, the there is a different solution).